# Alignment of items inside and outside Beamer {columns} environment

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I've noticed that items inside and outside Beamer's `columns` environment are not aligned horizontally. Is there a way to fix this?

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item item outside columns
    \item item outside columns
\end{itemize}

\begin{columns}
    \column{.6\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item in first column
    \end{itemize}

    \column{.4\textwidth}
    text in second column
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item item outside columns
    \item item outside columns
\end{itemize}

\begin{columns}[totalwidth=\textwidth]
    \column{.6\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item in first column
    \end{itemize}

    \column{.4\textwidth}
    text in second column
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of the resulting slide]

For a document-wide solution, you can use the `onlytextwidth` class option (requires beamer v3.65 or newer)

```
\documentclass[onlytextwidth]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item item outside columns
    \item item outside columns
\end{itemize}

\begin{columns}
    \column{.6\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item in first column
    \end{itemize}

    \column{.4\textwidth}
    text in second column
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, setting `totalwidth=\textwidth` or simply use the option `onlytextwidth` would solve my problem. No need for the `1.02` scale factor.

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right. I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: @KevinC These items are not _horizontally_ aligned. They are _vertically_ aligned. ;-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit: I never really understood the distinction between horizontal vs vertical alignments. But I thought my issue is more consistent with the tag description of _horizontal_ alignment: "adjusting the horizontal position of several equation or table components". In my case, it's the adjustment of horizontal position of several items.

Comment: @KevinC The straight line that connects your items is vertical. So your alignment is a _vertical_ alignment.

Answer (score 4):

To add to [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter)'s answer, the following picture illustrates the effect of passing the option `[totalwidth=\textwidth]` (or equivalently `[onlytextwidth]`) to the `columns` environment.

[image]

As one can see from scenario 4, by default, the `columns` environment occupies the whole `\paperwidth`. Thus in scenario 3, there is extra space between two columns when their total width is only `\textwidth`, which is shorter than `\paperwidth`. With the `onlytextwidth` option specified, the `columns` environment takes the same width as `\textwidth`, and so the horizontal alignment of items is correct, as shown in scenario 2.

### Code

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\colwidth[1]{\tikz{
    \draw[|-|](0,0)-- node[fill=white]{\texttt{#1}} (\textwidth,0);
}}

\newcommand\colenv[3][]{
    \begin{columns}[#1]
        \column{.6 #2}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item in first column
        \end{itemize}
        \colwidth{.6\textbackslash{}#3}

        \column{.4 #2}
        text in second column
        \colwidth{.4\textbackslash{}#3}
    \end{columns}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\alert{1. Outside \texttt{columns} environment}
\begin{itemize}
    \item item outside columns
\end{itemize}
\colwidth{\textbackslash{}textwidth}

\bigskip

\alert{2. \texttt{columns} environment with width options}
\colenv[onlytextwidth]{\textwidth}{textwidth} % equivalently, [totalwidth=\textwidth]

\bigskip

\alert{3. \texttt{columns} environment w/o width option, width=\texttt{\textbackslash{}textwidth}}
\colenv{\textwidth}{textwidth}

\bigskip

\alert{4. \texttt{columns} environment w/o width option, width=\texttt{\textbackslash{}paperwidth}}
\colenv{\paperwidth}{paperwidth}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```